# STM32F031K6 HAL UART Interrupts problem

Tags: microcontroller, uart, stm32, interrupts, stm32f0

[image]I got a new STM32F0 31 K6 nucleo board and I need to make a GSM UART interface on that board. I need to send an AT and receive an OK from the GSM board as a first step.I am able to transmit AT successfully
But cannot receive anything. I am using IAR.
I am using PA9 - TX and PA10 - RX.
How to create a transmit and receive code using interrupts using this HAL library.
I wrote code using interrupts and it's not giving a single character. 
This is my code

```
     int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  /* Configure the system clock to 48 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();
    /* Configure LED3 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED3);
  UART_Init();
  BSP_LED_Off(LED3);
  if(HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, TXBUFFERSIZE,100)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

    if(HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&UartHandle, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer,6) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
   /*##-5- Wait for the end of the transfer ###################################*/   
  while (UartReady != SET)
  {
  } 
    /* Reset transmission flag */
  UartReady = RESET;
  /*if(HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (uint8_t*)aRxBuffer, 6,1000)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }*/
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

IRQ handler

```
void USARTx_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&UartHandle);
}
```

Receive callback function

```
void  HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle)
{
  if(UartHandle->Instance == USARTx)
  {  
    /* Set transmission flag: transfer complete */
    UartReady = SET;
    BSP_LED_On(LED3); 
  }
}
```

And when I am debugging the code stuck at this point .

```
/*##-5- Wait for the end of the transfer ###################################*/   
  while (UartReady != SET)
  {
  }
```

My actual application is to send an SMS to the GSM board using UART and collect the reply in a buffer and then parse it.First i need to make this interface 
And I cannot use DMA as there is no idea on how much data is received on this commuunication.

please help guys..

Regards,
olivia

Comment: I recommend starting by putting up some minimal compilable code that doesn't do what you think it should do, along with any insights you've gotten from attempts at debugging.

Comment: Please do the following... Read this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Ask a specific question, and provide all details relating to your question. A good question doesn't need clarification. What GSM interface? What communication bus? SPI I2C or RS232 (to name a few). These types of questions shouldn't have to be asked.

Comment: @laptop2d It's UART according to the title. But it is unclear as it should have been included in the question body.

Comment: @OliviaChristy If you have a code which does not work, you should add that into the question as well. And a schematic maybe, make sure you did not mixed the RX-TX lines.

Comment: Add schematics as well, flow control is disabled or enabled by default on the module?

Comment: flow control pins are available on the mcu PA0 and PA1. but it function as ADC in and ADC out on the headers.

Comment: What is the flow control config regarding the GSM module? Also I am not interested in the Nucleo board's schematic, I am intetested in your schematic how did you connected the GSM module with the Nucleo. Maybe you should try to send and receive inside the main, multiple times. Basically your code seems to be fine (correct callback and Interrupt handler) but the hell knows what your GSM module expect as you still not added a datasheet.

Comment: hi guys I made it. Anybody having a problem with interrupt uart in stm32 boards using hal library please follow this link. http://letanphuc.net/2015/09/stm32f0-uart-tutorial-5/#comment-278 It helped me

Answer (score 3):

A basic UART initialization with interrupts using HAL looks something like the one below. I do not want to descirbe the parameters as they are quite obvious. It is an actual pins configuration and the UART peripheral configuration. `HAL_UART_MspInit` is called by `HAL_UART_Init`, to use it you only need to call `MX_USART1_UART_Init`.

```
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONEBIT_SAMPLING_DISABLED;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);
}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
    __USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA2     ------> USART1_TX
    PA3     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);       
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);               // Enable Interrupt
  }
}
```

The interrupt handling is the following:

```
void USART1_IRQHandler()
{
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
}
```

This is the actual ISR, and `HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1)` is a HAL definied handler function. It checks which interrupt source flag has been set, calls a callback or wait for more byte to be received and clears the interrupt flags.

In case of RX interrupts this handler counts the received bytes and when the desired amount is received calls this callback function:

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  if (huart->Instance == USART1)
  {
    // Your buffer is full with your data process it here or set a flag
  }
}
```

The callback has a weak declaration, you have to implement it.

Now about usage. To send, the following HAL function can be used, this is the simplest:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)"AT\r", 3, 0xFFFFFF)
```

To receive with interrupt one must use the following function:

```
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t size)
```

where `pData` is a pointer to the receive buffer and `size` is the number of bytes you are expecting. The `HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1)` will call the callback if the number of received bytes equal to `size`.

All of this can be generated by using [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) code generator, except the callbacks, those are not generated.

---

The GSM module probably has echo mode enabled by default, so to `AT\r` it will respond with `\r\nAT\r\n\r\nOK\r\n`, 12 bytes should be waited.

Echo mode can be disabled by `ATE0` command and saved as default with the `AT&W` command. From that the answer will be `\r\nOK\r\n` to the `AT\r`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced similar problem with my LTE module. It turns out that lots of such modules have Hardware flow control enabled by default. You can use HW flow control at your end as well or simply ground modules's CTS pin.

Also for some reason in my case the labelling for RX/TX and RTS/CTS was reversed. So i the above soluton did not work out you can try with swapped connections.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the discussion! I faced the similar problem. In my case I enabled interrupts (NVIC_EnableIRQ), wrote HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() and HAL_UART_Receive_IT() call.

But I missed this:

void USART1_IRQHandler()
   {
       HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
   }

Without the handler above the interrupt can't be catched by HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback() and the app. enters an endless loop, as it sees no interrupt handler.