# USART interrupt not working as expected [STM32 Nucleo]

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, serial, uart, interrupts

could someone explain why i can only receive 13 chars with USART interrupt? I use '\n' to detect the end of string.
[image]

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

char receive_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char receive_data;
int receive_index = NULL;
int data_ready_index = NULL;

void USART2_receive(void const * argument){
         for(;;){
                if(data_ready_index == 1){
                HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)"Received data: ", strlen("Received data: "));
                HAL_Delay(50);
                HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)receive_buffer, strlen(receive_buffer));
                memset(receive_buffer, NULL, sizeof(receive_buffer));
                HAL_Delay(50);
                HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)"\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));
                data_ready_index = NULL;
                }
         }
     }

    void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {

        if (huart->Instance == USART2){
            if (receive_data != 13){
                receive_buffer[receive_index++]=receive_data;
            }else{
                    receive_index = NULL;
                    data_ready_index = 1;                                                               
                    // Received data ready to be processed
            }
      }
    }

    void USART2_IRQHandler(void){

      HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
      HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *) &receive_data, 1);
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you send it without the CR or in smaller chunks?

Comment: Funny that you say that you check for `\n` but your code is checking for `\r` which is 13 and you only process 13 bytes, but then why is `strlen` giving more than 13 and sends some 0x00 bytes with them (<0>) - the message you get back is the length of the transmitted message just the content of the last 3 bytes is wrong.

Comment: @Trevor_G if i send in smaller chunks (less then 14) it is ok, everything works fine. And if i send without CR it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Ya I meant if you send 12345678 then send 12345678 +CR what do you get back.

Comment: @Trevor_G this what i got:
Received data: 1<0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0


16:06:36.636> >231231231231231231234567812345678

Comment: do it again..(or twice)  do you  get the same thing

Comment: After sending 1 time without CR and 1 time with CR. Repeated twice.  
16:12:57.286> Received data: 1234567812345<0><0><0> 
 
16:13:00.722> Received data: 1234567812345<0><0><0

Comment: YA I think the first crap is because you do not initialize the buffer.. But I also think you are receiving the data in the wrong spot. See this cross post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/266976/139766

Comment: What happens if you try to send "abcdefghijklmno"

Comment: @Trevor_G STM32 CubeMX does not generate **void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* huart)** function so maybe it is not necessary.@MITU RAJ If i send "abcdefghijklmno" i get **abcdefghijklm<0><0>**

Comment: Can you reduce the baud rate and check again ?

Comment: @MITURAJ I have reduced baud rate to 9600 and then i send same string i get **ab<0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0><0>**. So it is maybe problem with baud rate?

Comment: Did you change both your stm32 and the terminal baudrate to 9600  ?

Comment: Yes, they are both 9600.

Comment: If it had worked at 9600, we could have concluded that high baudrate was the problem.

Comment: Good catch...thats exactly why things got worse at slower baudrate, overflow happened at the rxbuffer on PC side.

Comment: I guess you can now write down the answer to your own question.

Comment: This is not the first time then delays mess everything.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. In the **void USART2_receive(void const * argument)** function i increased delay from 50 to 100 and then everything works fine. As @MITURAJ mentioned this may be caused by buffer overflow.

```
void USART2_receive(void const * argument){
    for(;;){
        if(data_ready_index == 1){
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)"Received data: ", 
            strlen("Received data: "));
            HAL_Delay(100);
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)receive_buffer, 
            strlen(receive_buffer));
            HAL_Delay(100);
            HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)"\r\n", strlen("\r\n"));
            data_ready_index = NULL;
            memset(receive_buffer, NULL, sizeof(receive_buffer));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the delay, and why did increasing it fix the problem?

Comment: I just don't know how to mark someone comment as helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

Finding that you need a longer delay should tip you off that you are not waiting for the Tx to actually finish. HAL_UART_Transmit_IT uses an interrupt to send bytes out (it is non-blocking). You are basically telling it to transmit, waiting a little bit, and cramming data into the buffer again before the transmit is done!

Instead I suggest that you monitor the callback to HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback and once that happens set some flag. In your USART2_receive function, wait for the flag to be set before asking it to send things again. Remember to clear the flag before waiting for it to be set again :)

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation, it quite tought to implement these changes as i am junior developer. Maybe there is any examples which i could follow for this feature?

Comment: @Into_Embedded, it is pretty straight forward, it is like the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback function. The CubeMx probably generates the TxCpltCallback function for you and you just have to fill it out. Take a look at the STM32 examples too, there should be something there for non-blocking UART.

Comment: i will definetly look into now it doesn't look so taught as it looked first.